# XSL XPATH if statement in tokenize()

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-3.0

I have an XML document containing lists of people structured like this:

```
<listPerson>
 <person xml:id="John_de_Foo">
  <persName>
     <forename>John</forename>
     <nameLink>de</nameLink>
     <surname>Foo</surname>
     <role>snake charmer</role>
  </persName>
 </person>
 <person xml:id="John_de_Foo_jr">
  <persName>
     <forename>John</forename>
     <nameLink>de</nameLink>
     <surname>Foo</surname>
     <genname>junior</genname>
  </persName>
 </person>
 <person xml:id="M_de_Foo">
  <persName>
     <forename>M</forename>
     <nameLink>de</nameLink>
     <surname>Foo</surname>
  </persName>
 </person>
 [...]
</listPerson>
```

I am extracting only certain fields and concatenating them with `tokenize()` to create a new element `<fullname>` using XSL 3.0 (where $doc = current document):

```
<xsl:template match="listPerson/person"> 
 <fullname>
   <xsl:value-of select="$p/persName/name, $p/persName/forename, $p/persName/nameLink, $p/persName/surname, $p/persName/addName, $p/persName/genName" separator=" "/>
 </fullname>
<xsl:template/>
```

Outputs:

```
<fullname>John de Foo</fullname>
<fullname>John de Foo junior</fullname>
<fullname>M de Foo</fullname>
```

But, I'd like to treat the element `<forename>` with a specific test. If the `forename/@text` is a single initial, add `.` . The new result would output:

```
<fullname>John de Foo</fullname>
<fullname>John de Foo junior</fullname>
<fullname>M. de Foo</fullname>
```

Also, the `<forename>` element may not exist, in which case it should bypass the test.

I can do this by changing the `tokenize()` to a series of `<xsl:if>` statements, but I'd rather try to solve it within XPATH if possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is rather confusing, I see no `ana` attribute in your sample, you haven't shown us the declaration of the key you are trying to use, your XSLT outputs no `fullname` elements at all in your shown code snippet, yet you show output with e.g. `<fullname>John de Foo junior</fullname>`. If the question is only about outputting `pers/forename` with a full stop appended in case of a single letter use `pers/fullname!(if (string-length() eq 1) then . || '.' else .)` should suffice in XPath 3.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to keep the post to the problem code. Code now updated. Everything else in this code works fine. I am concatenating various elements to create a new element called `fullname`. In this concatenation I want to treat the `forename` field to add a `.` only in the case where it is one character in length (ie. an initial).

Comment: I simplified the code to reflect only the problem. It was a recursive code looking for info from other documents. This now just concerned with a simple transformation.

Answer (score 5):

In XPath 2.0 there is an [if-then-else expression](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-conditionals) which you can use directly in the `xsl:value-of` like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$p/persName/name, if (string-length($p/persName/forename) = 1) then concat($p/persName/forename,'.') else $p/persName/forename , $p/persName/nameLink, $p/persName/surname, $p/persName/addName, $p/persName/genName" separator=" " />
```

An alternative is using the if-then-else in the `concat(...)` function:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$p/persName/name, concat($p/persName/forename, if (string-length($p/persName/forename) = 1) then '.' else ''), $p/persName/nameLink, $p/persName/surname, $p/persName/addName, $p/persName/genName" separator=" " />
```

Comment: I've tried both solutions, and neither has an effect, ie neither produces the `.` Is the implementation of `if` in XPATH dependent on the processor? I am using Saxon 9 HE.

Comment: That's strange. I tested it with Saxon 9 HE, too.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the `forename` to be suffixed with a full stop if it has a string length on one you can in XPath 3.1 use `forename!(if (string-length() eq 1) then . || '.' else .)` e.g.  in a full template:

```
  <xsl:template match="persName">
      <fullname>
          <xsl:value-of select="forename!(if (string-length() eq 1) then . || '.' else .), nameLink, surname, genname" separator=" "/>
      </fullname>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtq5

Will of course work the same with a different expression e.g. `$p/persName/forename!(if (string-length() eq 1) then . || '.' else .)`